# Should we merge the tag [instrument-identification] to [identify-this-instrument]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Standard identification tag is [indentify-this-xxx](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentify-this-xxx) so I suggest we keep [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument) so it is probably not necessary to keep both.

<s>Should we burn [instrument-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-identification)?</s>

Having enough points for [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument), I could (only) suggest a merge with [instrument-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-identification). People should vote for this merge now.

But I'm not sure which one will be the master though. I mean, it should be [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument), but I don't know how to actually do it.

Comment: Definitely not burn, but we could make them synonyms. Although due to the trend on the tags, I'd have instrument identification be the master since it's the one more used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently:

- 3 questions tagged with both [instrument-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-identification) and [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument) (1 unanswered),
- 12 questions tagged solely with [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument) (2 unanswered),
- 19 questions tagged solely with [instrument-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-identification) (5 unanswered).

I think these stats indicate that both tags are almost equally popular. Since we have a large number of identification tags in the standard format `[tag:identify-this-*]`, it makes sense to keep [identify-this-instrument](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-instrument) as the main tag and mark [instrument-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-identification) as its synonym.

I think it is helpful to mark synonyms in this case rather than burning the tags because a new user who wants to ask a question related to instrument identification could naturally type `identification` into the tagging box and this keyword should helpfully lead to `identify-this-instrument`. In fact, I think it's reasonable to have such synonyms for every identification tag, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `instrument-identification` should be dropped in favor of `identify-this-instrument` and the tags for existing questions switched over.

Even if we don't drop `instrument-identification`, we should still switch over the tags to match the standard form.