# Can we merge our synonymised tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retagging

Tag synonymization is [officially](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/313042) considered a precursor to merging. To quote from a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262288/313042) by @animuson♦ on Meta SE:

> [U]ltimately, this action *should* happen at some point. If everyone is too afraid to merge the tags together, then they probably shouldn't be synonyms.

We currently have [5 tag synonyms](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) that are yet to be merged (the links direct to the relevant discussions on Meta/chat):

- [[concert] → [live-music]](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/475/3955)
- [[backstory] → [history]](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/479/3955)
- [[effect-identification] → [identify-this-effect]](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/477/3955)
- [[videogame-soundtrack] → [soundtrack]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/conversation/discussion-on-synonymizing-videogame-soundtrack-with-soundtrack)
- [[instrument-identification] → [identify-this-instrument]](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/447/3955)

Can we merge all these tags to their synonyms? I don't see any advantage conferred by delaying the merging, short of disagreement on the synonymization itself — but with no such disagreement having risen up in months, it's safe to say that none exists.

<sub>1. This had been brought up in chat in the past [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53171427#53171427) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53495001#53495001).</sub>
<sub>2. Thanks to [@MicahWindsor](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/8989/micah-windsor) for bringing up tag merging in a [comment](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/do-we-really-need-the-song-title-tag-when-we-have-the-identify-this-song-tag#comment1383_661) under one of my answers! It reminded me of the past discussions on this matter, leading to this post.</sub>